# CSS Grid Responsive Image Gallery : Animation getting stuck on its way

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations, css-grid

On hovering the image, i wrote code for going on a animation from top.
But while animating, it gets stucked on its way and comes to place.I just want smooth transition. Can you guys help me to figure this out?

My codepen issue link : https://codepen.io/subin_s/pen/KYgxWX?editors=1100

```
<div class="grid-container">


  <figure class="grid_item grid_item-1">
    <div class="text" style="text-align:center;">
      JavaScript
      <button class="online_view">View Site</button>
    </div>
    <img class="grid_image" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/942500/pexels-photo-942500.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt="">
  </figure>


  <figure class="grid_item grid_item-2">
    <div class="text" style="text-align:center;">
      Bootstrap
      <button class="online_view">View Site</button>
    </div>
    <img class="grid_image"  src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/788946/pexels-photo-788946.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="">
  </figure>


<figure class="grid_item grid_item-3">
  <div class="text" style="text-align:center;">
      HTML / CSS
      <button class="online_view">View Site</button>
    </div>
    <img class="grid_image"  src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/17663/pexels-photo.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="">
  </figure>


<figure class="grid_item grid_item-4">
  <div class="text" style="text-align:center;">
      React JS
      <button class="online_view">View Site</button>
    </div>
    <img class="grid_image"  src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1927574/pexels-photo-1927574.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="">
  </figure>


<figure class="grid_item grid_item-5">
  <div class="text" style="text-align:center;">
      Wordpress
      <button class="online_view">View Site</button>
    </div>
    <img class="grid_image" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1647976/pexels-photo-1647976.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="">
  </figure>


<figure class="grid_item grid_item-6">
  <div class="text" style="text-align:center;">
      Grid/Flexbox 
      <button class="online_view">View Site</button>
    </div>
    <img class="grid_image"  src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/942500/pexels-photo-942500.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt="">
  </figure>


</div>
```

I have written the Animation code at the bottom, if you want to see it quick.

```
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  font-family: 'Raleway';
}

.grid-container {
  margin: 2rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns : repeat(3,1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 20vw);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.grid_image {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  object-fit:cover;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.grid_item {
  position: relative;
/*   overflow: hidden will prevent the image scaling to exceed the specified width. It will expand on back */
  overflow: hidden; 
}

/* .grid_item:hover {
  opacity: 0;
   animation: top_overlay 1s linear;
}
 */
/* .grid_item .after {
  position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
  left:50%;
  transform : translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
    font-size : 2rem;
    display: none;
    color: red;
} */

/* .grid_item:hover .after {
  display: block;
  background: #fff;
  object-fit : cover;
} */

.grid_item:hover .grid_image {
  transform : scale(1.1);
  filter: blur(2px);
}

.text {
  font-size : 1.2rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #C0392B;
  font-weight:900;
  display: none;
}

.online_view {
  margin-top: 40px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  outline:none;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}

button.online_view {
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

button.online_view:hover{
  background-color: #E8F6F3;
  color: #CA5D46;
}

.grid_item:hover .text {
  display: block;

/*   text to see, otherwise hides in the back */
  z-index: 999;
  animation : slide 0.5s ease;
}


@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    top:-100px;
  }

  25% {
    top: -75px;
  }

  50% {
    top: -50px;
  }

  75% {
    top: -25px;
  }

  100% {
   top:0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

avoid 3 animation breaks if you want to have a smooth transition. Below code you can try replacing:

```
.text {
  font-size : 1.2rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: -50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #C0392B;
  font-weight:900;
  opacity: 1;
}

.online_view {
  margin-top: 40px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  outline:none;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}

button.online_view {
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

button.online_view:hover{
  background-color: #E8F6F3;
  color: #CA5D46;
}

.grid_item:hover .text {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 9;
  animation : slide 0.7s ease forwards;
}


@keyframes slide {
  0%{
    top: -50%;
  }
  100% {
    top: 45%;
  }
}
```

Again, try to simplify your code.

Answer (score 0):

The stuck was happening because you added many steps in keyframes 0%,25%,50%,...Also i have changed the time for ease in the css classes and from grid_image style `ease-in-out` to `ease-in`.

Replace the your code with the css below.

```
.grid_image {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  object-fit:cover;
->transition:0.5s ease-in; or transition:all 0.5s ease-in;
}

.grid_item:hover .text {
  display: block;
  /*text to see, otherwise hides in the back */
  z-index: 999;
->animation : slide 0.7s ease-in;
}

    @keyframes slide {
      0%{
        top:-100px;
      }

      75% {
        top: -25px;
      }
```

Comment: I have made those changes, but still the animation is not smooth

Comment: okay... but still the issue is there. You can view that in the attached codepen link

Comment: @Subin `.grid_image: transition:0.5s ease-in`

Comment: @Subin delete the 25% from keyframes and check again.